# nfs-server.service won't start, bad exportfs entry persists

Tags: nfs, zfs, proxmox

I'm using Proxmox and ZFS. Previously, I had set up an NFS share using `sharenfs`, on a now removed zfs pool (panzer). Over a year has passed, and I'm trying to set up a new NFS share. When I run `systemctl status nfs-server.service`, I get the following message, showing a bad exportfs entry (with the old zfs pool - panzer):

```
systemctl status nfs-server.service
● nfs-server.service - NFS server and services
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nfs-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2023-09-20 21:39:02 MDT; 18min ago
  Process: 17766 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/exportfs -r (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 17767 ExecStopPost=/usr/sbin/exportfs -au (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 17768 ExecStopPost=/usr/sbin/exportfs -f (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Sep 20 21:39:02 matt-daemon systemd[1]: Starting NFS server and services...
Sep 20 21:39:02 matt-daemon exportfs[17766]: exportfs: duplicated export entries:
Sep 20 21:39:02 matt-daemon exportfs[17766]: exportfs:         192.168.2.0/24:/grizzly
Sep 20 21:39:02 matt-daemon exportfs[17766]: exportfs: duplicated export entries:
Sep 20 21:39:02 matt-daemon exportfs[17766]: exportfs:         192.168.2.0/24:/grizzly/backups
Sep 20 21:39:02 matt-daemon exportfs[17766]: exportfs: Failed to stat /panzer/media: No such file or directory
Sep 20 21:39:02 matt-daemon systemd[1]: nfs-server.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 20 21:39:02 matt-daemon systemd[1]: nfs-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 20 21:39:02 matt-daemon systemd[1]: Failed to start NFS server and services.
```

`/panzer/media` is a zfs pool that is no longer present on my system. Running `zfs list` shows that only grizzly is present, not panzer:

```
zfs list
NAME                    USED  AVAIL     REFER  MOUNTPOINT
grizzly                 834G  6.01T      157K  /grizzly
grizzly/backups         140K  6.01T      140K  /grizzly/backups
grizzly/vm-102-disk-0  25.3G  6.01T     18.9G  -
grizzly/vm-109-disk-0   808G  6.01T      696G  -
```

`/etc/exports` doesn't contain anything, and `/etc/exports.d/zfs-exports` did contain a line for panzer, which [contrary to the explicit message at the top of the file] I manually deleted in desperation. `/var/lib/nfs/etab` contains a line for panzer, and if I delete it and re-run `exportfs -r`, it returns.

Any help to fix my NFS installation, or wipe out the stale exportfs entry would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try running `exportfs -a` manually? Try running `exportfs` without options and then `exportfs -u path...` for extraneous ones?  Try rebooting after fixing the exports files?

Comment: @user10489 I’ve tried all 3 suggestions with no success, but thanks.

Comment: The point of running those commands is to see if you get interesting errors or output.   Just running them blindly isn't going to help.

Comment: I think the problem might be the duplicate errors on grizzly and grizzly/backups.   Another place to look is in the systemd units files for /panzer/media.  I'm not sure about your system but they are typically in /etc/systemd/system/  for user files and /usr/lib/systemd/system/ for system and package maintained entries.

Comment: @user10489 I get the same errors as what's shown in the systemctl output above when I run exportfs -r.

Comment: @user103944 I'll look into that, thanks.